# Meaning of random variable as a power

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expectation

Let's say we have random variable $X$, that is a map $X:Events \rightarrow \mathbb R$.  What is the meaning of $$z^X$$ (where z is complex perhaps).

Would I be able to treat X as a real number and say that $$\mathbb E [z^X] = \mathbb E [z(z)...(z)] = \mathbb E[z](\mathbb E[z]) ... (\mathbb E[z]) = (\mathbb E[z])^X$$ ?  After all, X is a map onto $\mathbb R$

Comment: Why are you adding up values of $z$? $X$ is a power like any other; you have, essentially, $E[z^X]=\sum_x z^x P(X=x)$ (with caveats for non-discrete $X$).

Comment: MY MISTAKE lol.  I will edit

Comment: No, you definitely can't do that. When written the way that I wrote, you see that this is really a very basic algebra error.

Comment: $E[Y^2] \not = (E[Y])^2$ (unless the variance of $Y$ is zero), so that is not what happens when $X$ is a real number

Comment: Your expressions do not make much sense. First of all $z$
is a complex number so we would just have $E[z]=z$. Also the left hand side is a real number while the right hand side contains X which is a random variable. Maybe you meant $E[z^X]=z^{E[X]}$ but this is also not true. The manipulations here remind me of the classic: $\frac{d}{dx}[x^2] = \frac{d}{dx}[x+x+\ldots+x]=1+1+\ldots+1=x$. The mistake in both places is in a not valid use of $[\ldots]$.